# How can i get the timezone name from timestamp using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this timestamp string `July 29, 2022 02:23 AM EDT` and I want to extract the `EDT` timezone name from it using moment.js. Is there any method provided by momentjs. I didn't find any option.

Can you help?

Comment: if the date format remains the same then just convert that date object into string and split it with 'AM'.

Comment: Why would you need `momentjs` at all for this? That is just string manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way will work for you.

```
var dateString = 'July 29, 2022 02:23 AM EDT';
var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
var momentObj = moment(dateObj);
var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split it

```
const date = "July 29, 2022 02:23 AM EDT";
const dateSplited = date.split(' ');
console.log(dateSplited[dateSplited.length-1]);
```

or you can use `getTimezoneOffset()` from Date, it's almost the same.

or for momentjs `zone.abbr(timestamp);`, documentation [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/abbr/)